# Filepicker.io - Limit number of files

Tags: filepicker.io

I'm wondering if Filepicker.io has the ability to limit the *number* of files a user can pick/upload? Looking through the [docs](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/) I can only find `maxSize` which limits the *size* of the individual files. Is this currently possible? If not, any plans on supporting this in the future? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Filepicker.io doesn't currently support this, but it's a reasonable request, we'll see if we can squeeze it in to our near-term roadmap

Comment: Wondering if there's been any development on this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Maciej Witowski that sounds very awesome thanks. Is it possible to use maxFiles with the Filepicker widget way.

Like `data-fp-maxFiles="x"`? while still using `data-fp-multiple="true"`

I couldn't find it in the documentation, and I've tried to test the code. I assume it's a no?

Answer (score -1):

We have just added a max_files option to limit the number of files.

Example: form.filepicker_field(:filepicker_url, max_files: 5)

Cheers,